# iOS App Development - Downloading large content using JSON

Tags: ios, ios6

We have a Universal iOS app. We use JSON to download content into the app during the first launch.

The size of content being downloaded on iPad (due to large image sizes) is about 100MB and on iPhone (smaller images) 80MB.

It takes about 4-7 minutes to download all content over WiFi. On 3G it takes 7-10 minutes.

Images are large in size, text content is not so much.

Is there any way we could reduce the download time? I'm aware of JSON compression but not sure if it will help with images?

Any ideas?

Tx

Comment: There are certain libraries for this

Comment: Why not use standard zip? Check and see if compressing these on your mac indeed reduces the size. If so, use one of many open sources to extract a zip on iOS.

Comment: What's "JSON compression"? JSON is not a compression algorithm/format... and how do you want to "download files using JSON"? I can't really make sense of that phrase...

Comment: Using JSON to download images makes no sense. You have to convert the image data to base64 encoded strings. This makes the data much larger. A zip file with the images would probably me much smaller (even though the images won't compress much if any).

Comment: You could also download the JSON only and load the images after, when needed.

Comment: Does your business logic require this? why not break up the json? just send what's required, and when it's required. A better way for images is to send the url, then do asynch downloading of the image.

Comment: Another question to think about: Could you just bundle the content with the app?

Comment: Thanks all for answering.

Comment: Here are clarifications. JSON compression - I read it somewhere that JSON can be compressed. Google for "JSON compression" gives some clue on it. Images are not downloaded via JSON as such. JSON contains the image URL and app downloads images. No encoding of images are involved. Image zip - download - unzip - makes sense. We can try that. Loading images when required - It might overload server a lot, also images will not be available when using offline. It's a recipe app and all images are of very high resolution as images are main feature of the app.

Comment: Based on the feedback you guys have provided I think the best way forward is to try either zipping images or download images when they are required.

Comment: On another notes I just wanted to know how do the big apps which have, let's say thousands of images, access images? My best guess would be the "download when required" logic?

Comment: @iMartin Bundling the app with image inflates the size too much. We used to have this in the initial version which we changed to JSON method which seems to be better as we have more control over content modifications, image changes etc. With JSON it truly becomes a dynamic app. If we bundle then even to correct a simple spelling mistake we have to rebuild it.

Comment: I think, you have reached your goal only when you can finish 100 MByte in less than a minute. Unless you have a _lot_ of objects and have to save them into Core Data this goal is realistic. On Wifi, an iPad can load and write data to disk roughly 6 MByte per second. Since the CPUs are not fully utilized, you can simultaneously parse the JSON, create Foundation objects, and decode  images. Again 6 MByte JSON per second, including parsing and creating Foundation objects. There is plenty time left to save those objects to disk (simultaneously).

Comment: Other hints:  To improve the approach, don't load images via JSON. Load them on demand as binary data with HTTP requests. Also, JSON will be usually compressed on the HTTP level already.

Comment: Tx CouchDeveloper your inputs are in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this information has been mentioned in various comments, but it's what I would have suggested anyway and I figured having an answer written up would be more useful, so here goes:

1. Instead of storing the location of each image in the JSON file and downloading them one at a time, store the images in zip files and download those. Any amount of compression you get from this is an improvement in your download time, and you can simply unzip the images once you've downloaded the zip files.
2. Store a reasonable amount of the images in the main bundle along with the app. In your case you clearly can't store them all there; you don't want to have a huge app, and since it's a recipe app I presume you'll be adding more recipes as you go along. It makes a lot more sense to be able to update and download recipes via the JSON than to have to push a new version of the app to the app store with each change. But there are some items that can be bundled with the app; ex. large background images, design elements that are constant and unlikely to change. Any image which won't be likely to need updating should be bundled with the main app; any savings on download time is an improvement.
3. *Have some kind of interesting loading screen.* This is very important since you're talking about 4-10 minute download times.  That is a *long* time for a user. When engaging with an application, 30 seconds can even seem like a long time. You're going to be hard pressed to make me willing to sit there and wait for 10 minutes for the app to begin if nothing is happening during that time. Have creative vegetable characters move across the screen, include a little interactive puzzle or ingredients on the loading screen, something. Just give the user something to look at (or preferably something interactive to *do*) while they're waiting. Otherwise you're probably going to lose a lot of users during this download.
4. If you can make this work, it really is a good idea to only download items when necessary. For example if your recipe app is broken into "Salads", "Fish", "Chicken", "Desserts", etc., you could prompt the user to download the recipe information for each category the first time they click on it. The great thing about this is that it breaks up the time the user has to spend waiting on the download; let's say you have 10 recipe categories, now the time the user has to wait all at once has been decreased from 4-10 minutes to 30 seconds-1 minute. That is a *huge* difference. I'll wait 1 minute for the Dessert recipes (still give them something to do!) much more readily than I'll wait 10 minutes for the whole app.

   4b. You mentioned not being able to access new content while offline, which is a valid concern. To address this you could have a prompt the first time the app loads: `This application contains hundreds of exciting recipes and delicious images. It can take several minutes to download all this yummy information. You can download all the content now, or proceed to the app and download recipes by category when you wish to view them. Please note that this will require an internet connection.` And the buttons could say something like `Download Now` and `Proceed to App`. Obviously you can play with the wording to your heart's content, but the idea is sound. You've informed the user that there might be a significant download time, so at least they're forewarned, and they can make their own decision about how to use your app.
5. However you decide to proceed, break up the content you download into logical categories for the zip files. For example, "Desserts.zip", "Salads.zip", etc. That way even if you don't decide to let the user download on-demand now, you've set up a structure that is open to change later on.

Comment: Tx WendiKidd for such detailed answer. It certainly clarify the things.